# Parse complex JSON Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sbjson

I want to parse complex json data coming from server in following form:

```
    {

    "Data 1":{
        "2012-12-01":[
            {
                "field 1":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 2"
            },
            {
                "service":"service 3",
                "summary":"summary 3"
            }
        ],
        "2012-12-10":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 2"
            }
        ],
        "2012-12-31":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Data 2":{
        "2013-01-4":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 2"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 3",
                "summary":"summary 3"
            }
        ],
        "2013-01-8":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 2"
            }
        ],
        "2013-01-25":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Data 3":{
        "2013-02-09":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 2"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 3",
                "summary":"summary 3"
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

How do I parse it using SBJSON?

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any of your stock parsers will return the JSON parsed into an array/dictionary "nest".  For Objective-C there are a half-dozen different "brands" of parsers, most free.  You feed the JSON string in and it returns the "nest".

Comment: Use an online JSON parser such as http://json.parser.online.fr/ to "visualize" the JSON.

Comment: I would need help in parsing with SBJSon parser, pls help

Comment: Read the [online documentation](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/api/3.0/annotated.html).  There is a method that converts string to object and another that converts object to string.  You want the first.

Comment: (Once again, the people voting to close were too lazy to find the dupes, so they used a bogus closing reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your JSON looks something like this when "pretty printed" --

```
{
    "Data 1":{
        "2012-12-01":[
            {
                "field 1":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 2"
            },
            {
                "service":"service 3",
                "summary":"summary 3"
            }
        ],
        "2012-12-10":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            },
            {
                "field":"field 2",
                "summary":"summary 2"
            }
        ],
        "2012-12-31":[
            {
                "field":"field 1",
                "summary":"summary 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Data 2":{
        "2013-01-4":[
```

The outermost part of the JSON is a dictionary (JSON calls it an "object") -- you can tell because of the opening `{`.  In that dictionary is a key/object pair called "Data 1".  The object is a dictionary (another `{`) whose first key/object pair is called "2012-12-01".  The object of this second pair is an array (the `[`) containing three dictionaries.  Etc.

Comment: what is solution in this case ? i am also stuck for converting json to c# class object -{
  'aa-AA': {
    lanCODE: 'aa-AA',
    genNames: {
      female: ['Wavenet'],
      male: ['Bavenet', 'Bavenet'],
    },
    default: 'Wavenet',
    systemLocale: ['ara', 'aru', 'are', 'aro', 'arh', 'arm', 'arq', 'ark'],
    name: 'xxxx',
  },
  'aa-AA': {
    lanCODE: 'aa-AA',
    genNames: {
      female: ['Wavenet'],
      male: ['Bavenet', 'Bavenet'],
    },
    default: 'Wavenet',
    systemLocale: ['ara', 'aru', 'are', 'aro', 'arh', 'arm', 'arq', 'ark'],
    name: 'xxxx',
  }
 }

Answer (score 2):

To parse the JSON is a one line command. If you want to use the JSON parser built into iOS 5 and later, [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it's just:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&error];
```

If you want to use [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework), it's:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [parser objectWithData:data];
```

Anyway, now that you've got your JSON in a `NSDictionary`, you can go ahead and navigate it appropriately, e.g.:

```
NSDictionary *data1 = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Data 1"];
NSArray *arrayDecFirst2012 = [data1 objectForKey:@"2012-12-01"];
NSDictionary *firstDictionaryInDecFirst2012 = [arrayDecFirst2012 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fieldOne = [firstDictionaryInDecFirst2012 objectForKey:@"field 1"];
```

Or, if you want to use the new subscripting notation, that would be:

```
NSDictionary *data1 = dictionary[@"Data 1"];
NSArray *arrayDecFirst2012 = data1[@"2012-12-01"];
NSDictionary *firstDictionaryInDecFirst2012 = arrayDecFirst2012[0];
NSString *fieldOne = firstDictionaryInDecFirst2012[@"field 1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used SBJSON specifically but by the looks of it you should be able to just do:

(this is assuming your JSON is currently an NSString)

```
NSDictionary *arrayOfJSONString = [SBJsonObject objectWithString:jsonString];
```

or something similar to that.

I personally will use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) sometimes. It is small, just a .h/.m to include in your project. (It is also included in RestKit). In this case you would just do:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
```

Then you can use it like:

```
NSDictionary *dataOne = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Data 1"];
```

If you would like to create Objc-C classes instead I would take a look at [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)

Answer (score 1):

Please read this tutorial step by step

[**Working with JSON in iOS**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

Please let me know still you get any trouble